# php to parse ps aux | grep ... results

Tags: php, regex

I have a system script that runs and pipes the results of "ps aux | grep utilities" to a textfile and chowns the textfile so the web service can read the file and display the results in my web app.

Here is an example of the raw results:

```
user     12052  0.2  0.1 137184 13056 ?        Ss   10:00   0:00 php /home/user/public_html/utilities/runProcFile.php cust1 cron
user     12054  0.2  0.1 137184 13064 ?        Ss   10:00   0:00 php /home/user/public_html/utilities/runProcFile.php cust3 cron
user     12055  0.6  0.1 137844 14220 ?        Ss   10:00   0:00 php /home/user/public_html/utilities/runProcFile.php cust4 cron
user     12057  0.2  0.1 137184 13052 ?        Ss   10:00   0:00 php /home/user/public_html/utilities/runProcFile.php cust89 cron
user     12058  0.2  0.1 137184 13052 ?        Ss   10:00   0:00 php /home/user/public_html/utilities/runProcFile.php cust435 cron
user     12059  0.3  0.1 135112 13000 ?        Ss   10:00   0:00 php /home/user/public_html/utilities/runProcFile.php cust16 cron
root     12068  0.0  0.0 106088  1164 pts/1    S+   10:00   0:00 sh -c ps aux | grep utilities > /home/user/public_html/logs/dashboard/currentlyPosting.txt
root     12070  0.0  0.0 103240   828 pts/1    R+   10:00   0:00 grep utilities
```

As my php script parses this textfile, I only need to extract the following (just an example):

```
cust1
cust3
cust4
cust89
cust435
cust16
```

I have tried a number of different clumsy ways and nothing seems to work well. The way I have listed below works, but sometimes grabs garbage too because the number of "spaces" in a line to explode on changes.

```
public function showProcesses() {
    $lines = file(DIR_LOGGER_ROOT . "dashboard/currentlyPosting.txt");
    $results = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        if (preg_match("/php/i", $line)) {
            $userProcess = explode(" ", $line);
            if($userProcess[29] != "0:00" && strlen($userProcess[29]) < 20) {
                $results[$i] = $userProcess[29];
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Could a few of you post elegant solutions for this please? I am trying to learn better ways of doing things and would appreciate the guidance.

Comment: If you're writing a command-line app to do this, I suggest using a language better suited to string handling and regexes like Perl.  You could probably even find something on CPAN to access the process table directly, like http://search.cpan.org/dist/Proc-ProcessTable/

Comment: the data is gathered and written to the textfile from a system script. it makes the textfile accessible to my web app without using exec and root from my web app. but parsing the results is for the web app itself so php makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead of `explode` and split on `[ ]+` (one or more spaces). But I think in this case you could go with [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and [capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
preg_match_all('/[ ]php[ ]+\S+[ ]+(\S+)/', $input, $matches);
$result = $matches[1];
```

The pattern matches a space, `php`, more spaces, a string of non-spaces (the path), more spaces, and then captures the next string of non-spaces. The first space is mostly to ensure that you don't match `php` as part of a user name but really only as a command.

An alternative to capturing is the "keep" feature of PCRE. If you use `\K` in the pattern, everything before it is discarded in the match:

```
preg_match_all('/[ ]php[ ]+\S+[ ]+\K\S+/', $input, $matches);
$result = $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_match()`. I do something similar for many of my system management scripts. Here is an example:

```
$test = "user     12052  0.2  0.1 137184 13056 ?        Ss   10:00   0:00 php /home/user/public_html/utilities/runProcFile.php cust1 cron
user     12054  0.2  0.1 137184 13064 ?        Ss   10:00   0:00 php /home/user/public_html/utilities/runProcFile.php cust3 cron
user     12055  0.6  0.1 137844 14220 ?        Ss   10:00   0:00 php /home/user/public_html/utilities/runProcFile.php cust4 cron
user     12057  0.2  0.1 137184 13052 ?        Ss   10:00   0:00 php /home/user/public_html/utilities/runProcFile.php cust89 cron
user     12058  0.2  0.1 137184 13052 ?        Ss   10:00   0:00 php /home/user/public_html/utilities/runProcFile.php cust435 cron
user     12059  0.3  0.1 135112 13000 ?        Ss   10:00   0:00 php /home/user/public_html/utilities/runProcFile.php cust16 cron
root     12068  0.0  0.0 106088  1164 pts/1    S+   10:00   0:00 sh -c ps aux | grep utilities > /home/user/public_html/logs/dashboard/currentlyPosting.txt
root     12070  0.0  0.0 103240   828 pts/1    R+   10:00   0:00 grep utilities";

$lines = explode("\n", $test);

foreach($lines as $line){
        if(preg_match("/.php[\s+](cust[\d]+)[\s+]cron/i", $line, $matches)){
                print_r($matches);
        }

}
```

The above prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .php cust1 cron
    [1] => cust1
)
Array
(
    [0] => .php cust3 cron
    [1] => cust3
)
Array
(
    [0] => .php cust4 cron
    [1] => cust4
)
Array
(
    [0] => .php cust89 cron
    [1] => cust89
)
Array
(
    [0] => .php cust435 cron
    [1] => cust435
)
Array
(
    [0] => .php cust16 cron
    [1] => cust16
)
```

You can set `$test` to equal the output from exec. the values you are looking for would be in the `if` statement under the `foreach`. `$matches[1]` will have the custx value.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of spaces in your line between the values is variable, you could use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

You would just have to change:

```
$userProcess = explode(" ", $line);
```

to:

```
$userProcess = preg_split("#\s+#", $line);
```

`\s+` will match one or more spaces, tabs or other white-space characters.

Then you can get the penultimate item with:

```
$txt = $userProcess[count($userProcess) - 2];
```